AUX port, Internal Speakers and USB DAC not working
I installed Ubuntu 24.04 LTS 2 weeks ago, was happy that everything was working fine out of the box but wanted to try and get the LDAC codec working with my Bluetooth headphones.
So I followed the instructions on this GitHub page: https://gist.github.com/the-spyke/2de98b22ff4f978ebf0650c90e82027e
It ended up working, but now a few days later I have realized this has completely broken all other audio devices.
Internal speakers don't work or show up, aux port will not do anything, and if I plug my USB DAC it will not work, both internal audio and the USB DAC only show "pro mode" and "off" as a configuration option.
Configuration screen:

I tried working backwards in the steps, but somehow I ended up removing the GUI from Ubuntu (luckily that was a very easy fix) and basically realized I am way out of my dept here.
If someone could please help me restore functionality to my audio drivers, without having to reinstall Ubuntu, that would be amazing.

Without a version number it is impossible to even know what GUI or features you have. Please edit the question and add this critical info with edit. Not as a comment please.

How I ended up fixing this problem:

Following the instruction in this guide on how to completely replace Pulseaudio with Pipewire:
https://www.baeldung.com/linux/pulseaudio-pipewire-replace

pipewire.service status was showing errors because of the .conf file here: /etc/alsa/conf.d/pipewire-jack-x86_64-linux-gnu.conf, I deleted this because the contents made no sense.

Solved this error found in the pipewire.service status: mod.jackdbus-detect: Failed to receive jackdbus reply by following this forum post:
https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=408389


After this I rebooted and now everything works fine.
Internal mic, USB DAC, audio jack, HDMI port, they all show up again in Pulseaudio Volume Control program.
